# transfer checked lines to colorbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, colorbox

I want to transfer an array of checked lines to a colorbox, the following code doesnt work, has someone an idea ?

```js
$(function() {
  var kid = $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function(i) {
    var arr = [];
    arr[i] = $(this).val();
  });

 $("#kontakte_bezButton1_{kontakte_bez:rowNumber}").colorbox({
    href:"testpage1.php?kid=" + arr,
    iframe:true,
    innerWidth:850,
    innerHeight:400,
    opacity:0.1,
    overlayClose:false,
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you have defined `arr` in function

```
function(i) {
var arr = [];
arr[i] = $(this).val();
}
```

this `leave it for having only scope within that funct`,

you have to give it `global scope` to use it elsewhere , ie. you have to define it globally

define like this:

```
$(function() {
var arr =[];
```

Comment: ooh thanx, the script works now, but it doesnt find checked lines

Answer (score 0):

You should build an url get parameter string:

```
  <script>
         $(function() {
              var data = {kid:[]}; // we put here all checkbox value
              $("input[type=checkbox][checked]").each(function() {   //iterate over all checked checkboxes
                   data.kid.push($(this).attr('id'));           //push the id of checkbox to data.kid array
              });

              $("#kontakte_bezButton1_{kontakte_bez:rowNumber}").colorbox({
                   href:"testpage1.php?" + $.param(data),   //create $_GET parameter string
                   iframe:true,
                   innerWidth:850,
                   innerHeight:400,
                   opacity:0.1,
                   overlayClose:false
              });
        });
  </script>
```

The $.param function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) generates get parameter string from an object. in this example the result like this:

```
  kid[]=1&kid[]=4&....
  (in urlencoded format: kid%5B%5D=1&kid%5B%5D=4 )
```

Comment: in testpage1.php i have the line
    echo $_REQUEST['kid'];
but no checked line is in the array

Comment: I changed the code a bit (reading checkbox value attribute), Does all checkbox have value attribute ?

Comment: this is a sample line:
<input type="checkbox" id="kontakte_bezCheckBox1_1" value="1" name="CheckBox1" >

Comment: so you want to send the names of checked checkboxes ?

Comment: in the final version i will sent the ids of every line

Comment: like this:
<input type="checkbox" id="{kontakte_id}" value="1" name="CheckBox1" >

Comment: iam using firefox, when i check two lines and i look at the source code of the page, i cant see the checked value in the input tag, is that right ? normally a checked line should look like this
<input type="checkbox" id="{kontakte_id}" value="1" name="CheckBox1" checked>

Comment: i does not use firefox , so i does not now. 
But in firebug try the selector. and that is more relevant than firefox DOM tree.

Comment: i changed the selector, try again please
And are you sure that { and } characters allowed in id-s ?

Comment: it looks that i have to set the checked value per line myself with jquery, right ?

Comment: yes the brackets are allowed, because its a template file generated by codecharge, in the sitesourcecode i see the ids